# SSRS query on remote linked server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have configured `SSRS` on `Server1`.
`Server2` is linked to `Server1` in `sys.servers`.

All `queries/reports` link runs fine if I run `Server1` objects

I want to run report on a `Server2` objects

**Try 1**
I created a Shared Data Source to `Server2`, built query in a Shared Dataset.

```
SELECT Field1 FROM Table1
```

a) Preview - Runs fine

b) `Server1/Reports` throws this error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   The execution failed for the shared data set 'table1'.
>   (rsDataSetExecutionError) Query execution failed for dataset
>   'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) For more information about this
>   error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or
>   enable remote errors

**Try 2** I tried to use Server1, and link from there. So when creating a Dataset I used `Server1` as a source and built this query

```
SELECT Field1 FROM Server2.master.dbo.Table1
```

a) preview runs fine

b) `Server1/Reports` throws same error as above

NOTE: changing above query to OPENQUERY yields same thing

If I look at logs it says:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

it can connect to `Server1` datasource (since SSRS is installed on Server1), but can't connect to `Server2`. How can I grant that user access to `Server2`?

How I can fix above issue, so that report runs fine from `Server1/Reports` too

**NOTE**: I use SQL Server 2017

Comment: Have you by any chance looked into a dynamic connection string?

Comment: @Diego , I didn't . But shouldn't it work without that if it works in preview? And I don't need to run one report on a different servers. I have just 1 report which needs to be run from Server2

Comment: What kind of authentication is used?

Comment: @WolfgangKais , windows authentication. I updated the post with a log error, if that helps

Comment: Yes, thanks. Is using fix credentials in the shared datasource an option?

Comment: @WolfgangKais, As long as it works, what should I do for that?

Comment: Edit the shared datasource in the web portal and enter specific Windows Credentials to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Windows Authentication for the Report Server and again in the shared datasource. That means that the logged-in user token is passed to a second hop, Server2. To allow this, you will have to enable Active Directory Delegation.

Contact your network administrators and ask them to configure (at least constrained) delegation on Server1 to allow delegated connections to Server2 (at least to the SQL Server Service).

Comment: I created a service account. Where is web portal? Is that in Reporting Services configuration manager Web Portal URL?

Comment: Yes, that is the URL. You will have to enable delegation for the service account, not for the computer. Good luck! :-)